# Сравнение классов в Java

Tags: java, наследование

Имеется код:

```
this.setOnMouseDragReleased(event -> {
    if(event.getGestureSource().getClass() == Pane.class) {
        something();
    }
}
```

Если наш GestureSource является непосредственно Pane, то данное условие срабатывает, но в случае если GestureSource наследуемый класс от Pane, то ничего не происходит. Подскажите, какое решение использовать в данном случае, чтобы наше условие срабатывало не только от Pane, но и от всех наследуемых от него классов?

Comment: Используйте instance of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы узнать, является ли выбранный класс наследником какого-либо класса, либо им самим, используйте оператор [instanceof](https://www.baeldung.com/java-instanceof).

В вашем случае

```
this.setOnMouseDragReleased(event -> {
    if (event.getGestureSource().getClass() instanceof Pane) {
        something();
    }
}
```

**Предупреждение:** не стоит злоупотреблять вызовами `instanceof`, т.к. это очень затратная по времени операция.